# Differential equations when the flow vanishes at nonisolated points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-points, hamilton-equations

Almost all books on differential equations discuss [fixed points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilibrium_point) where the flow vanishes, i.e., for a system of the following kind
$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}} = f(\mathbf{x})
$$
points $\mathbf{x}$ where $f(\mathbf{x}) = 0$.

However, much of the discussion revolves around isolated fixed points.  But there can also be cases where the flow vanishes along a manifold, e.g., for the Hamiltonian system with the Hamiltonian $H = p^2x$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x} = \partial_{p}H &= 2px\\
\dot{p} = -\partial_{x}H &= -p^2
\end{align}
$$
and the flow vanishes on the $x$ axis since $p = 0$ there. (Strogatz discusses a very similar example in Problem 6.5.12 of his book on nonlinear dynamics.)
Is there a specific way of referring to this sort of "fixed manifolds" (for lack of a better word)?
Are there any generally applicable results for such non-isolated fixed points?